# MYSQL row sequence with SUM() and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sequence

I try to order my rows by user's total point.

`SUM` and `ORDER BY` working correctly. But also i want to add sequence numbers of rows.

When I try to use `@row_number` I get some numbers but sequence is incorrect.

[image]

correct num column order should be **1,2,3,4** because I use order by total_point of sum of user's points.

How can I get correct sequence for num column?

```
SELECT 
users.user_id, 
users.user_hash, 
(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
sum(total_point) as total_point

FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t,user_stats
LEFT JOIN users on users.user_id = user_stats.stats_user_id
WHERE create_date BETWEEN "2020-04-01 00:00:00" AND "2020-04-30 23:59:59"
GROUP BY stats_user_id
ORDER BY total_point DESC
```

v: mysql 5.7

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: 5.7 so I can not use 8's new ROW_NUMBER function

Comment: why downvote? any reason?

Comment: Not downvoted by me. But I can see how some may be irked by you not following https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it is probably because there are no data to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the with total sorted rows and give them a number

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    user_hash,
    users.user_nick,
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
    total_point
FROM
    (SELECT 
        users.user_id,
        users.user_hash,
        users.user_nick,
        SUM(total_point) AS total_point
    FROM
        user_stats
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = user_stats.stats_user_id
    WHERE
        create_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY stats_user_id
    ORDER BY total_point DESC) t1,
    (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
ORDER BY num ASC;
```